# My vscode terminal is taking a long time to accept an input

Tags: visual-studio-code, input, codeblocks, mingw-w64

[this is from vs code, it took almost 3 seconds to eco back the input I typed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ac7Vl.png)[this image shows 65 seconds to run the code in codeblocks]
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68zwl.png)I am using MinGW compiler for my VS Code. Every time I am giving some input from the terminal, it is taking a long time to echo on the terminal. After that it takes very little time to print the output.
I am facing the same issue with Code::Blocks.
What can I do to make my terminals accept input normally (without any pauses or delays).
I am experiencing this issue for the last couple of weeks, but before that, there was no slow-echo-issue at all.

I uninstalled MinGW and VS Code along with all their directories multiple times and set them up again. But nothing has worked.

Comment: show your build flags. is this a debug build? what optimization flags are you using? actually- what _exactly_ do you mean by "_Every time I am giving some input from the terminal, it is taking a long time to show up on the terminal_"? You mean when you type a character, it takes a long time for that character to be echoed back by the terminal? because if so, the problem likely has nothing to do with VS Code, Code::Blocks, or your program- it would sound like a problem with your terminal or potentially your shell

Comment: Yes, it takes a long time to eco back after I have typed on my keyboard. It happens on both - vscode and Codeblocks. (Please forgive my ignorance - I didn't know the appropriate term was eco).
I ran my program on online c compiler - multiple times, it works just fine.
I have also tried to run different codes - but they all have the same slow-eco-issue.
The above screenshot is after I clicked build and run on codeblocks.(the long 32 bit numbers are just the binary form of given input)

Comment: the screenshot you showed was of a windows terminal. not of VS Code's integrated terminal, or of Code::Blocks. As I've said, if the problem is with character echo-back, then it's most probably a terminal-related problem. You should check if the same problem occurs in the [VS Code integrated terminal](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/basics).

Comment: yes it occurs in vs code terminal as well. i have added the screenshot. it took almost 3 seconds to eco back (my input was 2
7
3
1 2 3
8
5
1 2 4 8 16)

Comment: do you have any antivirus running on your machine? Ex. Windows Defender, McAfee, etc. And does this happen if you move your project to your C: drive and run it from there?

Comment: And does this happen only for giving input while the program is running? Or does it also happen once the program has stopped running and ended, and input is just going to the shell (in your case, PowerShell)?

Comment: yes, windows defender.
yes, the problem started when all my files were in c drive. so, I moved them out to d, now the same issue is happening.
it happens on both cases, while running and even when i have cleared the terminal(at vscode) and run again.

Comment: I suggest excluding your project folder from scanning by windows defender. If that's not enough, also make it ignore the VS Code executable.

Comment: I checked the protection history tab from windows defender and it says 
Detected: Trojan:Win32/Wacatac.B!ml
Status: Quarantined
......Affected items : file: D:\C codes\vscodes\container1.exe
(this is one of  the folders where I keep my code and all are giving the same notification)
What can I do now?

Comment: I think cleansing your system from malware is out of scope for SO Q&A...